# handle unhandled exceptions in Android

Tags: android, exception

In Windows phone 7, developers are provided an Application_UnhandledException event that provides an exception object containing information and stack trace of any unhandled exception that occurs.  There is an opportunity to store this object in local storage.  On next startup we can check for such an object and email it to the developer.  Obviously this is valuable in diagnosing production crashes.

Does such a thing exist in Android?
Thanks, Gary

Comment: Maybe [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler.html)?

Comment: A--C, Yes, that got me on the right track.  Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
java.lang.Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(UncaughtExceptionHandler handler)
```

Is this what you want?

Comment: your response led me to find the answer.  As it turns out it was in my commonsware 4.0 book on android development pp1467. Thanks

Comment: I am very glad to this hint helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Extend Application class

```
import android.app.Application;
import android.util.Log;

public class MyApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new UncaughtExceptionHandler() {

            @Override
            public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex) {
                Log.e("MyApplication", ex.getMessage());            

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Add the following line in AndroidManifest.xml file as Application attribute

```
android:name=".MyApplication"
```