# convert string to joda datetime gets stuck

Tags: java, jodatime, datetime-format

I'm trying to convert this string: `2014-01-01 00:00:00`  to Joda DateTime

I have tried the following:

```
public static DateTime SimpleIso8601StringToDateTime(String date) {
    DateTimeFormatter df = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(CONSTS_APP_GENERAL.SIMPLE_DATE_FORMAT);
    return df.parseDateTime(date);
}
```

And also the following:

```
public static DateTime SimpleIso8601StringToDateTime(String date) {
    DateTime dtDate = DateTime.parse(date, DateTimeFormat.forPattern(CONSTS_APP_GENERAL.SIMPLE_DATE_FORMAT));
    return dtDate;
}
```

Where

```
public static final String SIMPLE_DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS";
```

However, using the debugger I get to the formatting line and then while trying to process it the program cursor never comes back.

I should mention that this is an Android project.

Any ideas what might be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

It’s because `2014-01-01 00:00:00` doesn’t match the pattern `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS`—there’s no fractional part on the seconds in your input.

The result is that an unhandled exception gets raised—I’m not familiar with how Android handles those, the thread probably just dies unless you [set a handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14249035/handle-unhandled-exceptions-in-android). But putting the `parse()` call inside a `try` block should let you recover.

Comment: Thank you. But this doesn't seem to be the case. I have changed the pattern to perfectly match the String in vain. I have tried many ways to convert that String to DateTime or LocalDate with no success. It always performs the same, when I get to the conversion line the program cursor disappears as if something is happening in the background and never comes back, with no sign of exception or crash. Any ideas?